# Value comes back undefined despite being present in the object

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am having trouble getting access to a value in an object in my Express app after being successfully retrieved from a Mongo DB collection.

Here is the code.

```
app.post("/api/validate", async (req,res) => { 
  console.log('validating with id -> ', req.body.uid._id)
  try {
    User.findById(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.uid._id)).then(response => {
      console.log('The response object -> ', response) // logs the object
      console.log('Type ->', typeof(response)) // logs 'object'
      console.log('Value -> ', response.isAdmin) // logs undefined

      if(response.isAdmin === true) { // never triggered
        res.json({ authorized: true, result: response, message: 'User Authorized' })
      } else {
        res.json({ authorized: false, message:'User not authorized' })
      }
    }) 
  } catch (error) {
    res.json({ message: 'User not found.', err: error })
  }
})
```

Here is a simplified log of the response.

```
{
  userName: 'Tom Smith',
  userId: '0',
  comment: 'New Admin test',
  isAdmin: true,
}
```

The problem is the `isAdmin` value is always undefined so the `if` condition never gets triggered. If anyone can help me figure out what is going wrong here I'd much appreciate it.

Comment: What does the User schema look like?

Answer (score 0):

Try with a callback instead of resolving the Promise with `then`:

```
app.post('/api/validate', async (req, res) => {
  console.log('validating with id -> ', req.body.uid._id);
    User.findById(
      req.body.uid._id,
      (err, user) => {
        if (err) return res.json(err);
        if (!user) return res.json({ message: 'User not found.' });

        console.log('The response object -> ', user); // logs the object
        console.log('Type ->', typeof user); // logs 'object'
        console.log('Value -> ', user.isAdmin); // logs undefined

        if (user.isAdmin === true) {
          // never triggered
          res.json({
            authorized: true,
            result: user,
            message: 'User Authorized',
          });
        } else {
          res.json({ authorized: false, message: 'User not authorized' });
        }
      }
    );
});
```